# .htaccess in root not to interfere with subdomain rules?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

In root of the primary domain i have this .htaccess rules so that every non-www urls would redirect to
www.domain.com-urls:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but then i set up a subdomain via Cpanel on my VPS (it adds subdomain as a subdirectory, i.e. /sub) that is:

```
sub.domain.com
```

and all the urls get redirected now
to:

```
www.subdomain.com urls
```

and i need there only non-www urls, i.e.:

```
www.sub.domain.com -> sub.domain.com
sub.domain.com -> sub.domain.com
```

how do i make it that the root .htaccess for domain.com would not interfere with the subdomain .htacess rules?

because i will be adding more subdomains, which will require their own htaccess rules, and be all non-www, what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional condition and check only for "domain.com":

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```